# React-Admin useUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I would like to see if there is a way to prevent a refresh and use the hook "useUpdate" in React-Admin.

Use case would be I am emplimenting a auto save feature for my form and save it on the back end.

I'm currently using **useUpdate** but with the nature of my form, a reload would not be a good UI because the form could be 50-100 fields long. So a user could be editing a field close to the end and auto save will send them back to the top of the page.

I still want to use the data provider. Currently this is only being used to Edit a record

Comment: What refresh are you talking about? React-admin uses the return value from `dataProvider.update()` to update the record in the local store. If this return value isn't reflecting your changes, you should probably rework your dataProvider. Also, `useUpdate` per se doesn't trigger a page refresh - it's a side effect that you must trigger by using `useRefresh` in the onSuccess side effect.

Comment: Im sorry yes its more of an entire store update and re-render that is causing a "refresh" and breaking my form. Essentially, My form state is cleared after I useUpdate and it causes the entire page to re-render. I ended up just calling the dataprovider directly, to by-pass default admin behavior. thank you for the comment!